# String to Long (base 16) in Java

Tags: java, string, variables, long-integer

Given a string in java, how can I make it a Long in base 16? Just like this function does in Python: `newVariable = long(string, 16)`.
Thanks

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what "radix" is, never used that language. Is it the base?

Comment: Yes. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix.

Comment: @PM77-1 You should put that as an answer. Definition of Radix is here "In mathematical numeral systems, the radix or base is the number of unique digits, including zero, used to represent numbers in a positional numeral system. For example, for the decimal system (the most common system in use today) the radix is ten, because it uses the ten digits from 0 through 9."

Comment: Thanks! I get this error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "HereTheString With values 0 to F"  at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)` I checked and all the characters of the strings are between 0 and F, so I don't really know what's wrong

Comment: @deuseux12 **Long.parseLong("FFFF", 16) == 65535**

Answer (score 1):

if the string is decimal, and the expected result is hex:

```
String longStr = "123456789";

long l = Long.parseLong(longStr);

String hexStr = Long.toHexString(l);

System.out.println(hexStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String numberAsString = "ff";
long number1 = Long.valueOf(numberAsString, 16);
System.out.println(number1);
```

This will output you as
    255

Comment: I get this error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "HereTheString With values 0 to F" at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)`

Answer (score 0):

Use Long#parseLong(String, Integer) to convert Hex to Decimal.

Example with Base16:

```
System.out.println(Long.parseLong("F", 16))
```

Printed:
255

Same can be done with other bases, just change the Integer.

Answer (score -3):

you can convert like this

```
long var = Long.parseLong("16");
```

Comment: parseLong() parses the string "16" to base 10.

Comment: it should be `Long.parseLong(stringName, 16)`, right? But this gives me a java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)`` exception